# Type Mismatch Error when matching excel user profile to list of names in cells

Tags: excel, list

I am getting an error of Type Mismatch when the code runs to `userNames = .Range("A1:A100")`
. Not sure how this can be fixed, any suggestions?

```vb
Sub AddPix()

Dim userNames() As String
Dim userPixNames() As String
Dim currentUser As String
Dim myPassword As String
myPassword = "trade2013"
Sheets("Collection Slip").Unprotect Password:=myPassword

With Worksheets("User Management")
    'Assign the user names to an array (much faster than looping through range)
    userNames = .Range("A1:A100")
    userPixNames = .Range("B1:B100")
End With
For i = 1 To 100
    'The 1 in userNames(i,1) is needed because of the way
        'VBA creates an array assigned directly from a range
        '(as we did above)
    If Environ$("UserName") = userNames(i, 1) Then
        'Have I missed where the picture will be inserted?
        With Sheets("Collection Slip").Pictures.Insert _
            ("G:\ITS\Shared\Signature\" & userPixNames(i, 1) & ".jpg")
            .Top = Range("B31").Top
            .Left = Range("B31").Left
            .Width = 250
            .Height = 58
        End With
        'short-circuit the For loop when current user's name is found
        i = 100
    End If
 Next i
 'Sheets("Collection Slip").Protect Password:=myPassword
End Sub
```

In addition I have tired Dim userNames() as Variant instead of String. However error of "Type Mismatch" still occurs at 'userNames = .Range("A1:A100")

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `Dim userNames() as Variant` instead of `as String`. The array of values from the range are by default type Variant.

Comment: Hi I adjusted the code to Dim userNames() as Varient. However I am still facing the same error

Comment: What about `.Range("A1:A100").Value`?

Comment: You're close I think, but it should be `Dim userNames as Variant`, without the parentheses. You want to load the `Values` of the `Range` into a `Variant` not an array of them.